# Howto run git describe on a bare git respository?

Tags: git

I have a bare git repository on my host:

```
astropanic@localhost:~/production/repo$ ls -1
branches
config
description
FETCH_HEAD
HEAD
hooks
info
objects
packed-refs
refs
```

How I can run here

```
git describe
```

without cloning the repo to non bare (.git) ?

Comment: It doesn't work? On my machine I can `git describe` a bare repo. Maybe you have no tags in your bare repo. Can you print the output of `ls -al refs/tags`

Comment: that directory is empt.

It is a repo generated via capistrano3

Answer (score 0):

Your git repository doesn't use tags. For `git describe` you need a tag. A excerpt from the `man`-page:

```
The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit. If the tag
points to the commit, then only the tag is shown. Otherwise, it suffixes the tag
name with the number of additional commits on top of the tagged object and the
abbreviated object name of the most recent commit.

By default (without --all or --tags) git describe only shows annotated tags. For
more information about creating annotated tags see the -a and -s options to
git-tag
```

If you need `git describe` in a script than use the `--always` option in your describe call.

```
--always              show abbreviated commit object as fallback
```

Or use (annotated-)tags. Maybe you need to setup that the capistrano-clients fetch the tag informations. Then use `git fetch --tags` on every client.