# Use git description and parse value as a string inside bash script?

Tags: git, bash, variables

When I do a `git push live master` I want to check the version by using `git describe` on the server side, but when the below executes the variable is empty?

Since the repo is bare, maybe I cant access that, or inside the post-receive I cant execute or something?

```
#!/bin/sh
currentVersion=`git describe --abbrev=0`
echo $currentVersion
mkdir /var/www/example/public_html/projects/$currentVersion
git --work-tree=/var/www/example/public_html/projects/core --git-dir=/var/repo/cool.git checkout -f
```

I also tried this

```
#!/bin/sh
currentVersion=$(git describe --abbrev=0)
echo $currentVersion
mkdir /var/www/example/public_html/projects/$currentVersion
git --work-tree=/var/www/example/public_html/projects/core --git-dir=/var/repo/cool.git checkout -f
```

and this

```
#!/bin/sh
currentVersion="${git describe --abbrev=0}"
echo "{$currentVersion}"
mkdir /var/www/example/public_html/projects/"{$currentVersion}"
git --work-tree=/var/www/example/public_html/projects/core --git-dir=/var/repo/cool.git checkout -f
```

**EDIT:** I try to echo this `echo $(git describe)` and the result is `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.`. Unfortunately I don't think that I am able to execute that command on my server. If that is the case, can I pass data via git push (might need to look into that)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Howto run git describe on a bare git respository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945627/howto-run-git-describe-on-a-bare-git-respository)

If you indeed don't have any tags yet but want to test your hook change your git command to something like

```
currentVersion=$(git describe --always)
```

Also, make sure that the hook has permissions for execution.

Comment: Thanks, I assume the permissions are fine since I can `mkdir` and `cp`, Let me try that command. Wait the command won't work for me, I need just the `v0.0.1` not the id. The previous was no different.

Comment: As I said this command is just for testing. If you want your initial command to work just use tags. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed `git push live --tags`